# How to validate login/sign up form in header as drop down in Magento?

Tags: php, forms, validation, magento, authentication

I have changed the 'customer_form_login' reference name to header in 'customer.xml' and call 'getChildHtml('customer_form_login') ?>' in 'header.phtml' in the dropdown that I have created in through html and JavaScript.

But the problem is after entering the email and password, when I am clicking the login button its not redirecting to user page or user dashboard basically it is doing anything.

Comment: @halfer Can you help me on this problem ?

Comment: Not so much, I don't use Magento - I often just do editing to help present questions in a clearer fashion. My one bit of feedback is that the question is a bit brief, and I am left wondering if there are more details you can add. Do you have any plugins? Does Magento generate a debug log that can be consulted? Have you checked different browsers, since this might be a JS issue? Have you looked in your browser console(s) for errors? Please add any new substantive detail to the question.

Comment: oh no issues. I have solve it. Actually there was jQuery.min.js was conflicting with other. I just changed it to latest version and bingo it works.